# Increase IIS CPU usage

Tags: asp.net, wcf, asp.net-mvc-4, iis

I have Visual Studio 2015 on x64 machine (Intel i5, 8GB RAM, Windows 10) running a Windows Communication Foundation (WCF) service. The service runs for like 5 hours to process data and it uses the IIS Express web server. When it is running the CPU usage of the IIS is about 13% every time.

One time I noticed that the data was getting processed very fast and I looked at the Task Manager and the CPU usage of the process was about 40%, but I can't make the IIS process go to 40% again. I don't know what happened that increased the CPU usage to 40% that time.

Is there a way to increase the CPU usage of the IIS (Express) so that the computation runs faster and therefore the data gets processed faster? Is there any settings that can be changed to accomplish this. I think the CPU should be above 14% every time. Is there a setting that specifically restricted this CPU usage in the IIS settings?

Comment: It's probably something else that is the bottleneck.

Comment: You have a couple of settings to limit cpu in IIS, but I don't know if all configuration are available in IIS Express.
But as it has de appcmd, it's possible to configure a lot of things:
http://www.iis.net/configreference/system.applicationhost/applicationpools/add/cpu

Answer (score 0):

In IIS 8.5, there is `Limit (percent)` property per app pool settings which allows % of CPU time consumed by worker thread related to that app-pool